# Angular 2: Using Component Input to Pass Nested Arrays

Tags: arrays, angularjs, input, nested, components

Is there a better solution to passing complex objects to child components when the objects consist of nested arrays?

Here's my issue: in the partial html that appears in the child component, you'll have to represent nested arrays like this: `{{animal.quadripeds[2].dogs[4].furColor}}`

The index values are hard-coded.  It'd be nicer to see it like this, for instance: 
`animal.quadripeds.find(q => q.isDirty == true).dogs.find(d => d.isDirty == true).furColor.`  Unfortunately, you can't use the .find() in {{}}

Here's a plnkr for your enjoyment: [Nested Arrays via Component Input](http://plnkr.co/9lBZiLNGOSSd3zsgiRhW)

Thanks!

Comment: Just delegate this search to controller? It's not very readable to do in in template anyway.

Comment: Delegate it to a service instead @dfsq the controller is not for business logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `find` method in your template, but it does not mean that you can't use it in your component, for example :

```
import {Input, Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component(...)
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() transport: Transport;

    private _valueToDisplay;

    ngOnInit() {
        this._valueToDisplay = animal.quadripeds
            .find(q => q.isDirty == true)
            .dogs.find(d => d.isDirty == true)
            .furColor;
    }

    get valueToDisplay() {
        return this._valueToDisplay;
    }
}
```

Two things:

- Note that I use the `OnInit` interface : this is because your input property will not be initialized yet in your constructor (so be careful to implement your initialization logic in the `ngOnInit` function).
- You probably have to handle the same logic when your input property is updated, you can implement the `ngOnChanges` function (or use a setter for your input property).

Here is your updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/BTzAfO6AGSLnOn8S1l24

Note that, as suggested by @dfsq, this logic should probably go in a service.

Comment: Mickael, Thanks for the ngOnChanges tip!  To your point there probably is more flexibility in implementing it.  I haven't tried it in an update scenario, but it certainly works when you initially render the child component's view.